# Extracting a double from a string with text

Tags: c++, string

I have a string with lots of different characters similar to: "$: " "213.23453"
How do i extract the double value 213.23453 and store it in a variable, it's C++/C and i cant use lambdas.

Comment: [`stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: You first have to decide whether you're writing C or C++, because the answer is different for the two languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "poor man's regex" of the `sscanf` function to skip over the characters prior to the first digit, and then reading the double, like this:

```
char *str = "\"$: \" \"213.23453\"";
double d;
sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%lf", &d);
```

Note the asterisk after the first percentage format: it instructs `sscanf` to read the string without writing its content into an output buffer.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/9b6IBh).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

`[$]?[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]?[0-9]?`

This should match those with a $ sign and those without.

[Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) is a very good regular expression library

Personally, I find [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/xpressive.html) much nicer to work with. It is a header-only library and it has some nice features such as static regexes (regexes compiled at compile time).

If you're using a C++11 compliant compiler, use [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) unless you have good reason to use something else.

Comment: Note, however, that although `std::regex` with GCC 4.7 compiles just fine, it is actually very dysfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

Pure C++ solution could be to manually cut off the trash characters preceding the number (first digit identified by [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)) and then just construct a temporary [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) object to retrieve the `double` from:

```
std::string myStr("$:. :$$#&*$ :213.23453$:#$;");

// find the first digit:
int startPos = 0;
for (; startPos < myStr.size(); ++startPos)
    if (std::isdigit(myStr[startPos])) break;

// cut off the trash:
myStr = myStr.substr(startPos, myStr.size() - startPos);

// retrieve the value:
double d;
std::istringstream(myStr) >> d;
```

but C-style `sscanf` with appropriate format specified would suffice here as well :)